# How in REDCap do you create a [survey-url] to a new instance of a Repeating Instrument?

Tags: survey, redcap

How do you send a [survey-link] that creates/links to a new instance of a repeating-instrument survey in REDCap?

ie imaging you have customers who should visit you on a regular basis. You have two instruments:

- customer
- visit    [set as a Repeating Instrument + enabled as a Survey]

And you have an alert that regularly sends them a "Time for your next visit" email.

When I send an alert to a customer with [survey-link:visit] it will work the first time. The email will contain a unique URL for that customer's visit. But when the alert is sent a second time, person will open the URL and get a "Thank you for your interest, but you have already completed this survey."

I can manually (via the web admin) create a new instance of their Visit. But how should I do this automatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**As of version 12.5** this is now supported using a smart variable [new-instance] which, when appended to a [survey-url] or [survey-link] smart variable, will target a new instance of the instrument **if it is repeating**. In the same release came ASI options around repeating instruments, which allow you to repeat an ASI every X minutes, hours or days, and each successive ASI instance points to the specific instance of the survey instrument. This is useful for daily surveys.

For your use case, [survey-link:visit][new-instance] will do what you want. Send it to them once and instruct them to fill it out as many times as needed, or send it however many times you need to.

====

Yes, this is a current limitation. It has been requested of the REDCap developers to add a smart variable `[new-instance]` that can be appended to a `[survey-link]` or other smart variable to instantiate a new instance of a repeating instrument, and they have responded positively.

Maybe the most appropriate workflow here would be for you or the project staff to manually create the visit instance, save it with a date, and have an alert that sends them an invitation to complete the visit details, or whatever you need them to do.

If you want the respondents to instantiate the visit themselves (i.e., make a booking rather than respond to a booking made on their behalf), the only workaround I have personally managed is to enable the survey queue and activate the repeating instrument on the basis of some logic (say, `[consent] = 1`), and in the survey settings of the repeating instrument, enable the option to **Allow respondents to repeat the survey**.

With these settings, the survey queue will allow the survey respondent to create a new instance of the instrument themselves by clicking the 'Take this survey again' button (button text configurable in survey settings). They can be emailed their link to the survey queue via an alert using the smart variable `[survey-queue-link]` or `[survey-queue-url]`.

For extra credit, you could get fancy with the survey queue logic so that the instrument is *disabled* if, say, the last instance of the survey has today's date, using something like `[consent] = 1 and datediff([visit_date][last-instance],"today","d",true) > 0`. With this you could prevent them smashing it and adding multiple new visits at once.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer this, Jangari. In the end my work around was to create duplicate instruments out to the maximum period we required (14 days * 2 per day = 28 instruments) and then schedule them using Automatic Invites that were an offset from their registration date. That worked well enough (a bit ugly) but the worst was needing to duplicate Alerts for each event.

A few python scripts copies/audits/corrects all the duplicate instrument and alerts to keep them manageable. If [new-instance] arrives it will cut a out a lot of complexity in this project.